# How to create a dropdown menu from a list generated through find-each method (in a Rails app)?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In the navbar of my Rails blog-app I have the following piece of code that lists the available categories of articles that are available in the site.

```
<div class="">
      <% Category.find_each do |category| %>
        <small class="me-4"><%= link_to category.topic, category %></small>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Currently, it displays the categories as a horizontal listing across the navbar. I am trying to pack all these category listings into a dropdown menu using bootstrap, but I am having no success. This is what I have tried:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Philosophy topics
      </button>
      <% Category.find_each do |category| %>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <%= link_to category.topic, category, class: "dropdown-item txt-n me-4" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Nothing "drops down" when I click on the dropdown thus displayed. I have tried several other variations of where I place the class="dropdown-menu", all equally unsuccessful.

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to how to restructure this piece of code so as to obtain a working dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on bootstrap, but [the docs seem fairly insistent](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/) that you have a `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`, you have a `data-toggle` but no `data-bs-toggle`.

Also, you should have your `dropdown-menu` div outside the loop, so you only have one of them that contains a link for each category.